# How do I display the ~bounding box~ of a Render Border that is already created?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, interface, selection-tools, render-border

A beginner's mistake, but it's driving me crazy. How do these bounding boxes work? Sometimes they appear, sometimes they do not. I can not figure out how to enable them in order to resize manually the Render Border that is already created.

How Render Border is usually:

[image]

How is it when the bounding box accidentally appears in the Render Border:

[image]

What is the trick? How do I display the bounding box?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. Simply select the active camera for the bounding box to appear. :D